# How to run bitcoind (command line client) without connecting to other nodes?

Tags: blockchain, bitcoind, abe

I'm running Abe to create a blockchain SQL database, so I don't want the Bitcoin client to touch my copy of the blockchain at the moment. But I would like to query the blockchain with the bitcoind client. Is there a way to run bitcoind without connecting to other nodes?

Comment: iptables on bitcoin port?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I see two approaches:

1. Use `--connect <hostname>` with the hostname set to something that doesn't exist.
2. Unplug from the network.

Comment: -connect=0.0.0.0 should do.

Answer (score 1):

Now there is an extra option to disable automatic connections at startup:

1. CLI option `-noconnect`
2. Configuration option: `noconnect=1`